# How private shilded transactions to payee address works in ZeroCash from the information point of view?

Tags: zcash, zero-knowledge

In ZeroCash they perform transactions [like this](https://youtu.be/Rm-p8rrR9c8?t=1486). I want to unravel and understand how z-addresses work in ZCash. It shall be described simply in [here](https://electriccoin.co/blog/zcash-private-transactions/) and [in-depth, revised here](https://github.com/zcash/zips/blob/master/protocol/protocol.pdf) and [here (older, a bit simpler)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6956581). Simply put it shall be described here:

[image: Zerocash: Decentralized Anonymous Payments from Bitcoin, page 11/469]

or even simpler here:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Blue is what gets into the ledger including stuff like `cm`, `a_{pk}`, `hash(sn)`.

In simple terms here is how I understand the algorithm and please correct me if I am wrong: A payer (slide #5) passes a value onto the chain as if it is passed by the payee. And this where I stop getting it:

1. **How payer proves that he** indeed **can spend that value** if he makes it look like operation is done from payee's perspective?
2. If `value`, `rho`, `r'` and `r''` are passed in the form of payee's public key how does it not make such transaction capable to happen only once\or how is it checked and proved?
3. If a transaction can happen only one and payer needs to prove that he has funds for it how he can not be linked to that transaction?

Comment: Dear moderators, please do care to explains why the hall on bloody earth question on the fundamentals of one of the top five blockchain systems (zcash) is offtopic on a website about blockchain?!?

Comment: See: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic